# Display JavaScript Array Dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I'm a beginner at this.  I have a web design assignment (using Javascript and HTML5) that requires me to **use a do while loop** to prompt the user to enter a month and the amount of steps taken for that month.  This should dynamically populate a list in my HTML so the site should be displaying two columns with the values being input. For example:

Steps Entered:

Month:      Steps:

May           15000
 
June          20000
July          25000
... and so on...

Total Steps: 60000

My code isn't working.
**EDIT: Current problem is that it seems to be stuck in an endless loop.  'done' does not stop the prompt boxes and nothing is being populated on the site.**
Can anyone shed some light please?  Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
   function getSteps()
   {
    var months = new Array(); 
    var steps = new Array();
    var m = 0;
    var s = 0;
    var stepTotal = 0;
        
    do{
     months[m] = prompt("Enter a month or enter 'done' when finished:");
     document.getElementById("mlog").innerHTML = months[m] + "<br>";
     steps[s] = prompt("How many steps did you take?");
     document.getElementById("slog").innerHTML = steps[s] + "<br>";
     steps[s] = parseInt(steps[s]);
     stepTotal += steps[s];
     m++;
     s++;
    }while(months[m] != "done");
    document.getElementById("totalS").innerHTML = "Total Steps: " + stepTotal;
   }   
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Monthly Steps Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1>Count your steps!</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
   <h2>Click on the buttons below to enter the number of steps taken every month.</h2>
   <button onclick="getSteps();">Steps Log</button><br><br>
    <p>Steps Entered:</p>
    <p>Month<br>
    <span id="mlog">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p>Steps<br>
    <span id="slog">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p>Total Steps: <span id="totalS">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </section>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: "My code isn't working". Can you be more specific about what the problem is please? e.g. give an example of what you expect it to do, vs what it actually does right now. Otherwise people have to look carefully through all of it, or guess.

Comment: @ADyson My apologies!  I updated it!  Thanks!

Comment: it's document.getElementById, not document.getElementByID. Do not capitalize the letter D.

Comment: @peerbolte Thanks!  I fixed that.  Now it seems to be stuck in an endless loop. 'done' Does not stop the prompt boxes and nothing is being populated on the site.

Answer (score 2):

You test `months[m]` **after** you do `m++`,so there should be `months[m-1]`.
Better move that outside of loop.

```js
function getSteps() {
  var months = new Array();
  var steps = new Array();
  var m = 0;
  var s = 0;
  var stepTotal = 0;
  var month = prompt("Enter a month or enter 'done' when finished:");
  while (month && month != 'done') //pressed [cancel], empty or "done"
  {
    months.push(month); //months[m] = month;
    //document.getElementById("mlog").innerHTML += months[m] + "<br>";
    var step /*steps[s]*/ = parseInt(prompt("How many steps did you take?")) || 0; //0 replaces NaN
    //document.getElementById("slog").innerHTML += steps[s] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("tablelog").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + month + "</td><td>" + step + "</td></tr>";
    steps.push(step); //steps[s] = parseInt(steps[s]);
    stepTotal += step;
    m++;
    s++;
    month = prompt("Enter a month or enter 'done' when finished:");
  }
  document.getElementById("totalS").innerHTML = stepTotal;
}
```

```css
table,
td,
tr,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Monthly Steps Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Count your steps!</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h2>Click on the buttons below to enter the number of steps taken every month.</h2>
    <button onclick="getSteps();">Steps Log</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tbody id="tablelog">
        <tr>
          <th colspan=2>Steps Entered:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Steps</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Total Steps: <span id="totalS">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: also use += instead of = to append text to innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

If you check `months[m]` with console.log it's indefined, so you should check with `months[m-1]` If you necessary should use do while your script will looks like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function getSteps()
        {
            var months = new Array();
            var steps = new Array();
            var m = 0;
            var s = 0;
            var stepTotal = 0;

            do{
                months[m] = prompt("Enter a month or enter 'done' when finished:");
                document.getElementById("mlog").innerHTML = months[m] + "<br>";
                steps[s] = prompt("How many steps did you take?");
                document.getElementById("slog").innerHTML = steps[s] + "<br>";
                steps[s] = parseInt(steps[s]);
                stepTotal += steps[s];
                m++;
                s++;
                console.log(m);
                console.log(s);
                console.log(months[m]);
            }while (months[m-1] != "done");
            document.getElementById("totalS").innerHTML = "Total Steps: " + stepTotal;
        }
    </script>
```

And in the end it will still asks after you write 'done'. It's gonna be better just with while(). So if it's not necessary to use do while - use only while.